# Homebrew freezes when running brew doctor or brew --config

Tags: macos, homebrew, package-managers

A few days ago, homebrew started to stuck when I try to run `brew doctor` or `brew --config`. The output is:

```
$ brew --config
HOMEBREW_VERSION: 0.9.5
ORIGIN: https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew.git
HEAD: 391ed374442cb8f91d9168ccd23f1c97b84686d1
Last commit: 6 minutes ago
HOMEBREW_PREFIX: /usr/local
HOMEBREW_CELLAR: /usr/local/Cellar
CPU: quad-core 64-bit sandybridge
OS X: 10.10.1-x86_64
```

and

```
$ brew doctor
Please note that these warnings are just used to help the Homebrew maintainers
with debugging if you file an issue. If everything you use Homebrew for is
working fine: please don't worry and just ignore them. Thanks!

Warning: Setting DYLD_* vars can break dynamic linking.
Set variables:
    DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH: /usr/local/kde4/lib:/Users/<username>/Desktop/anderes/benvium-libimobiledevice-macosx-8507dd2
```

The only way to exit is sending a SIGINT to the process. Anyway, `brew update` worked:

```
$ brew update
Updated Homebrew from cd9895d9 to 391ed374.
==> Updated Formulae
curl         fwknop   john-jumbo   sshrc
$ brew update
Already up-to-date.
```

I tried [reinstalling homebrew](http://brew.sh/), but it does not seem to work:

```
$ ruby -e "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/master/install)"
It appears Homebrew is already installed. If your intent is to reinstall you
should do the following before running this installer again:
    rm -rf /usr/local/Cellar /usr/local/.git && brew cleanup
$ rm -rf /usr/local/Cellar /usr/local/.git && brew cleanup
$ ruby -e "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/master/install)"
/Users/<username>/.rbenv/shims/ruby: line 21: /usr/local/Cellar/rbenv/0.4.0/libexec/rbenv: No such file or directory
```

Surprisingly, the brew command itself does work even after the `rm` command above. I'm wondering what I'm doing wrong. Thanks for any help!

Comment: FWIW, the brew executable lives in /usr/local/bin, so nuking the Cellar doesn't get rid of it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got a solution now: xcode-select was pointing to the wrong directory. `sudo xcode-select -switch /Applications/Xcode.app` solved the problem.